# Different group results for GPResult -vs- "net users MyName /domain"?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I have a user that is set up as a member of "My Test Group".
When I am logged in as that user and do a `"GPResult /R"` that user does not appear to be a member of "My Test Group" but when I do `"Net users *MyUserName* /Domain"` they do appear to be a member of "My Test Group"

Why the difference? Ultimately I am using ASP.Net MVC Authorize attributes to allow access to specific controller actions.

Comment: Have you tried logging out and in again for the user? It might be that GPResult is showing group membership at time of login, while the net users command is pulling information straight from AD.

Comment: Yes with no difference.

Comment: Check your active directory infrastructure, is your replication healthy?

Comment: What kind of group? Global? Universal? Security? Distribution?

Comment: "Security Group - Global"